# How can I show an icon next to Text in xml file?

Tags: android, xml

I tried to code like this

```
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/ivIcon"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:src="@android:drawable/ic_btn_speak_now" />

    <TextView
        style="@style/behindMenuItemLabel"
        android:text="Item0" />
```

But it outputs like this. It's not in the same line :(

[image]

My whole xml code is just like this.
`(icon) item` will be a set, which will be clicked by a user to move on activity.
So I need grouping them together.

```
<LinearLayout style="@style/behindMenuScrollContent"
    android:paddingTop="25dp" >

    <TextView
        style="@style/behindMenuItemTitle"
        android:text="Subject" />

    <TextView
        style="@style/behindMenuItemLabel"
        android:text="Item0" />

    <TextView
        style="@style/behindMenuItemLabel"
        android:text="Item1" />

    <TextView
        style="@style/behindMenuItemLabel"
        android:text="Item2" />

    <TextView
        style="@style/behindMenuItemLabel"
        android:text="Item3" />

    <TextView
        style="@style/behindMenuItemLabel"
        android:text="Item4" />

    <TextView
        style="@style/behindMenuItemLabel"
        android:text="Item5" />

    <TextView
        style="@style/behindMenuItemTitle"
        android:text="Subject2" />

    <TextView
        style="@style/behindMenuItemLabel"
        android:text="Item6" />

    <TextView
        style="@style/behindMenuItemLabel"
        android:text="Item7" />

    <TextView
        style="@style/behindMenuItemLabel"
        android:text="Item8" />

    <TextView
        style="@style/behindMenuItemLabel"
        android:text="Item9" />

    <TextView
        style="@style/behindMenuItemLabel"
        android:text="Item10" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/behind_btn"
        style="@style/behindMenuItemLabel"
        android:text="BUTTON" />

</LinearLayout>
```

UPDATE: I don't need margin between icon and text but need margin only on left!

[image]

**style.xml**

```
<style name="behindMenuItemLabel">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">20dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">4dp</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">30sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#d2d2d2</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this :

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/behindMenuItemLabel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_weight="40"
    android:drawablePadding="-5dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="Speak Now"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    style="@style/behindMenuItemLabel" />
```

And this is your style.xml

```
<style name="behindMenuItemLabel">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">20dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">4dp</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">30sp</item>
    <item name="android:drawableLeft">@drawable/your_icon</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#d2d2d2</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks. Your one looks the one I'm expecting.  How do you do that if you are doing it with Style.xml?

Comment: Whats there in style(overhead) its the faster and relaible way to do this. If this worked for you then accept this answer

Comment: I will! One more thing I need from you is how to do that with using style.xml I have to use it many times in xml so I want it as style. Please see my UPDATE in question! and tell me how to modify my style.xml Please, customize my original style.xml

Comment: if you are trying to achieve the result mentioned in the post: use app:drawableLeftCompat instead of android:drawableLeft (it has changed over the years)

Answer (score 4):

your need be full filled using the drawable attribute of textview, below i am giving one example:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/bookTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:drawableBottom="@drawable/icon"
        android:text="Item 0"
        style="@style/behindMenuItemLabel"/>
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 4):

you can set icon at all four side of a text in `TextView`

**Right :**

```
android:drawableRight="@drawable/icon"
```

**Top :**

```
android:drawableTop="@drawable/icon"
```

**Bottom :**

```
android:drawableBottom="@drawable/icon"
```

**Left :**

`android:drawableLeft="@drawable/icon"`

Comment: Thanks it shows. but it seems there's the same margin between icon and text. How can I disable with keeping marginLeft?

Answer (score 2):

Do not use separate imageView for icon. 
In your textview set the drawable in right (or left,top,bottom)

```
 android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/ic_btn_speak_now"
```

Comment: Thanks it shows. but it seems there's the same margin between icon and text. How can I disable with keeping marginLeft?

Comment: Do you want to reduce the margin?

Comment: Yes, exactly but only margin between icon and text

Comment: use android:drawablePadding for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this attr `android:drawableLeft="your_drawable_id"` to set image left of text so the xml tag will be like this :

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/bookTitle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/icon"
    android:text="Item 0"
    style="@style/behindMenuItemLabel"/>
```

You can also set image right,top or bottom. Best wishes.

Comment: y left, bottom he needs i think.